# Faulty TRS jack question

Tags: audio, cable, volume, xlr

I purchased a new JBL Nano Patch+ volume control which sits between my computer audio output and a set of Yamaha HS7 monitors.

The jack in the left audio output needs to sit slightly recessed out the socket in order to obtain a signal of equal magnitude to that of the right speaker output.
With the jack all the way inserted into its socket the volume is considerably lower than the right channel, however still audible.

My best guess is that the switch (See photo below) is in a closed position with the jack completely inserted, possibly an elevated plate making connection whilst the jack is inserted.

If this is indeed the problem would it be worth my while attempting to repair the connector?
Else does anybody have an idea what the likely cause may be?

The Left-Jack works fine in the Right-Socket, the Right-Jack experiences the same problem in the Left-Socket.

From 3.5mm stereo mini jack to control: Procab CLA713 - 3.5 mm Jack male stereo to 2 x 6.3 mm Jack male
From control to monitors: Procab XLR male to 6.3 mm Jack male stereo

[image: Photo of jack in output socket]

[image: Audio socket]

Comment: Sounds like the sleeve does all the harm , for some reason the connection might be going to unbalanced (-6db) , its a faulty female connector , just change it !

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that there is a cut-off switch in the out socket, but it's unlikely. The device is completely passive, there would be no reason for the manufacturer to include a switch.

Anyway the the picture you show seems to be of a mono socket, the device has "stereo" sockets (actually a balanced line outputs) probably more like this one (if indeed it does not have a switch):

[image]

You are using an unbalanced signal, coming from your stereo, that you connect by means of the mono jacks on (each of the channels of) the input side. When you insert the mono jacks you are actually short circuiting the ring and sleeve (1 and 3 in the picture) of the input socket. That is fine, being an unbalanced signal, the proper way to use a balanced line is to short-circuit the "would be" minus to ground.

Now, the Nano patch connects passively "pin by pin" the inputs to the outputs, so this means that in the output side, if all is well, the ring will also be connected to ground.

This is a requirement to get a proper (unbalanced) signal on your monitors. The monitor will subtract the signals from pins 2 and 3 in the XLR connector (respectively, tip and sleeve of the jack; *the legend of the figure above is inconsistent with the pin numbering of XLR connectors!*)

If the ring of the jack is not grounded, the monitor will have no reference signal to subtract from the actual signal and will produce a weaker signal, which is consistent with your description of the problem.

Anyway, my advice is that you try first to clean the interior of the socket (try a compressed air can if you have one or just blow inside the hole and/or use a small pointed brush). Failing that, I thinks it's worth to open the box and try to see what's happening. After all it's a completely passive device, you may be able to detect visually the problem (if the connector is not enclosed, which may be the case in a high grade appliance).

Consider that if some day you want to use the device with a balanced source signal (like coming from a professional or semiprofessional mixing board), then you may not be able to use that channel, even with the recessed jack...